# Item not displaying when pushing data from asyncstorage to array object in React Native?

Tags: react-native, async-await, asyncstorage, react-native-community-netinfo

I am creating an App in React Native Expo and trying to display data using asyncstorage. The only data which is showing is of static array which I have declared in **var temp** but when I push the received item in var temp it is not displaying that. I tried using console.log(temp) to check if it is appending data to **temp variable**. The data is getting appended but is not displaying. Can anyone tell where I am going wrong here

Receiving data from async storage

```
readData = async () => {
        try {
            const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ticket')
            if (userData != null) {
                temp.push(JSON.parse(userData))
            }
            console.log(temp)
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        readData()
    }, [])
```

Displaying data

```
<View>
                <List.AccordionGroup>
                {
                    temp.map((rowData, index) => (
                        
                            <List.Accordion title={rowData.subject} key={rowData.id} id={rowData.id} style={{marginBottom: 10, backgroundColor: 'white', marginTop: 10,}}>
                                <View style={{padding: 20, backgroundColor: '#FAFAFA'}}>
                                    <Text style={{color: '#7658c1', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'flex'}}> Project Name:  </Text><List.Item title={rowData.name} />
                                    <Text style={{color: '#7658c1', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'flex'}}> Requested By:  </Text><List.Item title={rowData.request} />
                                    <Text style={{color: '#7658c1', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'flex'}}> Category:  </Text><List.Item title={rowData.category} />
                                    <Text style={{color: '#7658c1', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'flex'}}> Priority:  </Text><List.Item title={rowData.priority}/>
                                    <Text style={{color: '#7658c1', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'flex'}}> Location:  </Text><List.Item title={rowData.location}/>
                                    <Text style={{color: '#7658c1', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'flex'}}> Description:  </Text><List.Item title={rowData.desc}/>
                                </View>
                            </List.Accordion>
                        
                    ))
                    
                }
            
                </List.AccordionGroup>
                
            </View>
```

Storing data in AsyncStorage

```
handleSubmit = async () => {
        let temp = {
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
            name: "",
            request: "",
            subject: "",
            category: "",
            priority: "",
            desc: "",
            location: "",
        };
        temp.name = name
        temp.request = request
        temp.subject = subject
        temp.category = category
        temp.priority = priority
        temp.desc = desc
        temp.location = location
        console.log(temp);
        try {
            // await AsyncStorage.setItem("ticket", JSON.stringify(temp))
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('ticket', JSON.stringify(temp))
            console.log(JSON.stringify(temp));
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
```

Static Array

```
var temp = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "ECM DMS",
    request: "Sohail",
    subject: "Laptop Repair",
    category: "IT",
    priority: "Medium",
    desc: "Urgent Repair",
    location: "Pune",
}];
```

userData which is stored in asyncstorage

```
Object {
    "category": "Sharepoint",
    "desc": "Access",
    "id": 20,
    "location": "Mumbai",
    "name": "SharePoint access",
    "priority": "Low",
    "request": "Gurmar",
    "subject": "Access",
  },
```

Comment: you should use the useState hook and read the data from there.

Comment: I am using functional components so there is no use for render function. But I declared a static variable outside my function and trying to push in my temp var so why I need to declare it in useState

Comment: i reckon your ui is not re rendering itself when temp is updated so thats why

Comment: please show userData object that you have fetched dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full example of how you can use `AsyncStorage` to store and retrieve the data.

**Working App: [Expo App](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/belligerent-soda)**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import { List } from 'react-native-paper';
const temp = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'ECM DMS',
    request: 'Sohail',
    subject: 'Laptop Repair',
    category: 'IT',
    priority: 'Medium',
    desc: 'Urgent Repair',
    location: 'Pune',
  },
];
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    let temp = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      name: 'ECM DMS',
      request: 'Sohail',
      subject: 'Laptop Repair' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 200),
      category: 'IT',
      priority: 'Medium',
      desc: 'Urgent Repair',
      location: 'Pune',
    };

    // console.log(temp);
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('ticket', JSON.stringify([...data, temp]));
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(temp));
      setData([...data, temp]);
      AsyncStorage?.getItem('ticket').then((userData) =>
        console.log('read data submit:' + JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(userData)))
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('handle:', e);
    }
  };

  const readData = async () => {
    try {
      const userData = await AsyncStorage?.getItem('ticket');
      if (userData != null) {
        setData(JSON.parse(userData));
        console.log('read data:' + JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(userData)));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    readData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        {data.length > 0 && (
          <List.AccordionGroup>
            {data?.map((rowData, index) => (
              <List.Accordion
                title={rowData.subject}
                key={rowData.id}
                id={rowData.id}
                style={{
                  marginBottom: 10,
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                  marginTop: 10,
                }}>
                <View style={{ padding: 20, backgroundColor: '#FAFAFA' }}>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: '#7658c1',
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      display: 'flex',
                    }}>
                    {' '}
                    Project Name:{' '}
                  </Text>
                  <List.Item title={rowData.name} />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: '#7658c1',
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      display: 'flex',
                    }}>
                    {' '}
                    Requested By:{' '}
                  </Text>
                  <List.Item title={rowData.request} />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: '#7658c1',
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      display: 'flex',
                    }}>
                    {' '}
                    Category:{' '}
                  </Text>
                  <List.Item title={rowData.category} />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: '#7658c1',
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      display: 'flex',
                    }}>
                    {' '}
                    Priority:{' '}
                  </Text>
                  <List.Item title={rowData.priority} />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: '#7658c1',
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      display: 'flex',
                    }}>
                    {' '}
                    Location:{' '}
                  </Text>
                  <List.Item title={rowData.location} />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: '#7658c1',
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      display: 'flex',
                    }}>
                    {' '}
                    Description:{' '}
                  </Text>
                  <List.Item title={rowData.desc} />
                </View>
              </List.Accordion>
            ))}
          </List.AccordionGroup>
        )}
      </View>

      <Button title={'ADD MORE DATA'} onPress={handleSubmit} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: So if I am using getItem in one file and setItem in another do I need to declare const [data, setData] = useState([]); on both sides ?

Comment: you will need to declare state wherever you intend to render-render it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I will try this

Comment: Do consider accepting the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Sure it helped. But I find a bug in that sometimes the previous data also get lost or deleted. Can you tell me why it happens

Comment: I have not noticed it, let me check. Just ran it multiple times and I don't see any strange behaviors. Maybe there is some issue with Expo Snack or network on your side. Code is alright.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228292/discussion-between-dhanjay-bhardwaj-and-ketan-ramteke).

Answer (score 1):

For the UI level changes, you must have to use the state to tell the react-native to update UI when state value changes.

So you have to set temp as a state of your data.

For ex.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

and when you are about to update the data to show in your design then you have to update the state by calling the setData method and mutate the old state with the new state to update new data with the existing data value.

For ex.

```
setState(prevState => [...prevState, <<NEW_DATA_OBJECT>>]);
```

It will update the state and this is the way to show the updated data in UI,
you only have to use data const at the place of your temp and update state when your are handling the submission of new data.